# Is there a way to use the v_model for the Soldier in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

A while back in Team Fortress 2 not only was the Soldier's v_model changed to the c_model but morally **everything** was. Since I use the soldier the most, I was curious if there was a way to use or get a skin that looks like the v_model since it interferes with my performance.

Here are two images to compare the differences. This is the new one using the c_model:

[image: NEW]

This is the old one using v_model, which I would like the end result to look like:

[image: Old]

In conclusion I am asking if there is a way to use the v_model for the soldier, *if not*, would there happen to be a skin that would match this look?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/ufa4t/v_modelw_model_vs_c_model/ gives a bit more background on the two kinds of models.

Comment: Ok I will be sure to check it out!